# Git push prompts for username and password but pull doesn't why?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-push, git-pull

i am using Mac Osx and i want git pull to also query for username and password before pull.

### I have tried :

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

It works with "git push" but not "git pull" is there a way to enable username and password prompt for both?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need this? It doesn't ask on pull because the repository is (probably) public.

Comment: @tkausl thanks a lot! it just a requirement for a project. Will it prompt if it's private?

Comment: Question too incomplete. How is remote configured? Did server administrator set up to allow you to push? SSH or https protocol allowed.

Answer (score 0):

(in root user)Open the console and type :

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

We are telling git to disable the helper that avoids entering the password every time we execute these instructions. In this way, every time we pull or push from a repository, we will be asked for the password.